# Django python pagination always displaye the first 2, and last 2 pages

Tags: python, django, pagination

I have some pagination for a table. I have it so that it will only show 3 pages either side of the current page. However if I am on the 5th page, The first page disappears. I am trying to set it up so that the first two and last two pages of  the pagination are always visible regardless of what the current page is.

**code:**

```html
{% if is_paginated %}
    <div class="pagination">
        {% if current_page.has_previous %}
            <a class="page-link" style="font-size: 24px; padding: 2px;" href="?page={{ current_page.previous_page_number }}">&#171;</a>
        {% else %}
            <a class="page-link" style="font-size: 24px; padding: 2px;" href="">&#171;</a>
        {% endif %}
        {% for i in current_page.paginator.page_range %}
            {% if i == 1 %}
                {% if current_page.number == i %}
                    <a class="page-link active" href="">{{ i }}</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if i == 2 %}
                {% if current_page.number == i %}
                    <a class="page-link active" href="">{{ i }}</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if i != 1 and i != 2 %}
                {% if current_page.number == i %}
                    <a class="page-link active" href="">{{ i }}</a>
                {% else %}
                    {% if current_page.number|add:-4 == i %}
                        <a class="page-link" href="">...</a>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if current_page.number|add:3 >= i and current_page.number|add:-3 <= i %}
                        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if current_page.number|add:4 == i %}
                        <a class="page-link" href="">...</a>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if current_page.has_next %}
            <a class="page-link" style="font-size: 24px; padding: 2px;" href="?page={{ current_page.next_page_number }}">&#187;</a>
        {% else %}
            <a class="page-link" style="font-size: 24px; padding: 2px;" href="">&#187;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Update:**

I have worked out a jank way of having the first two pages always showing but cannot get the last two pages to always show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add some well place if statements to always display the first and last place.

I set it so that if `i == 1` show the page in the pagination navbar. Then during the loop of `i` I remove the first page and last page using `i != 1 and i != current_page.paginator.page_range|last`.

Using `current_page.paginator.page_range|last` will get the last value in the range and then you do the same for the last page as you did for the first page.

**Code:**

```html
{% for i in current_page.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if i == 1 %}
        {% if current_page.number == i %}
            <a class="page-link active" href="">{{ i }}</a>
        {% else %}
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if i != 1 and i != current_page.paginator.page_range|last %}
        {% if current_page.number == i %}
            <a class="page-link active" href="">{{ i }}</a>
        {% else %}
            {% if current_page.number|add:-4 == i %}
                <a class="page-link" href="">...</a>
            {% endif %}
            {% if current_page.number|add:3 >= i and current_page.number|add:-3 <= i %}
                <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a>
            {% endif %}
            {% if current_page.number|add:4 == i %}
                <a class="page-link" href="">...</a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if i == current_page.paginator.page_range|last %}
        {% if current_page.number == i %}
            <a class="page-link active" href="">{{ current_page.paginator.page_range|last }}</a>
        {% else %}
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ current_page.paginator.page_range|last }}">{{ current_page.paginator.page_range|last }}</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Screenshot:

[image]